# How to change the color of each link for the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am been search other forums but cant quite find the answer I'm looking for.

I want each link in my nav bar to be a different color. I have them right now as a shade of red but I want the other two to be a blue and a yellow.

My code:

```css
nav li a {
    color: #F73139;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>home</a></li>
        <li><a>work</a></li>
        <li><a>contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to assign different colors to them:

```css
nav li:nth-child(1) a {
    color: #F73139;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: blue;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>home</a></li>
        <li><a>work</a></li>
        <li><a>contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CLASS attribute to name that specific list item

for eg:

```css
li.one {color: red;}

li.two {color: blue;}

li.three {color: yellow;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a>home</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a>work</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a>contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```